# How can we update email in GlobalProtect?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, vpn

I am unable to connect to VPN, GlobalProtect is using wrong Email Id, I tried to find option where I can pass correct email but did not find anything,

[image]

[image]

Instead of that email which is showing in the attached snap, I want to user another correct EmailId, Sign out button is not showing in the GlobalProtect setting.

Any help will be appriciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign out your wrong account by => right lick your GlobalProtect icon => click the right top button => settings :

[image]

in General tag:

[image]

Comment: Sign out button is not showing in my case. I am using GlobalProtect 5.1.1-12

Comment: @Smash my version is 5.1.5-20, could you please have an update and check it again ?